# Не выводится текст на картинке PHP

Tags: php, изображения

Привет всем! У меня почему-то не выводится текст на картинку. Вот код:

```php
$random = rand(1000,9999);
$img = imagecreate(300,100);
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", 10000) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0 , pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: image/png");
$primaryColor = imagecolorallocate($img, 7, 188, 7);
$secondaryColor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $primaryColor);
$font = "/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf";
imagettftext($ing, 6, 33, 100, 50, $secondaryColor, $font, $random);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: `imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $primaryColor);`  опечатка в `$im` ......... ну и тут скорее всего тоже `imagettftext($ing,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас опечатки в коде, первая это:

```
imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $primaryColor);
```

Замените на:

```
imagefilledrectangle($img, 4, 4, 50, 25, $primaryColor);
```

И вторая:

```
imagettftext($ing, 6, 33, 100, 50, $secondaryColor, $font, $random);
```

Замените на:

```
imagettftext($img, 6, 33, 100, 50, $secondaryColor, $font, $random);
```

Вот из-за второй не выводит текст.